# Stuck at install

Tags: system-installation

I am stuck on the ubuntu logo when I try to install it. I pressed f6 and the last ting that it did was systemd-backlight@backlight: intel_backlight.service. Also i have an optimus laptop if that my be the problem.

Comment: The Ubuntu logo pops up during most forms of install. Can you please be more specific about what part of the install?

Comment: Did you verify the download was correct? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM   (If a single bit is wrong, problems can occur & its hours-days to debug compares to 2secs to verify iso)